# How to recover IOS & Android folder in react native.?

Tags: react-native

I am new to react-native I am facing an error that my IOS and Android folder are deleted by using this command (rm -rf node_modules ios android). Now I am trying to recover the IOS and Android folder by using these commands npm install--> react-native upgrade -->react-native run-ios.But no success and facing same issue
error iOS project folder not found. Are you sure this is a React Native project?.
Please help me.

Comment: Just create a new react native project with `react-native init` using the same name of your actual project as parameter and move the new android & ios folder to your actual project

Answer (score 0):

You should create a new React-Native project and copy all the source files to new project folder. Also, you should move your package.json to the new project folder but you need to change project name with the new one in your new project folder. After then,

```
npm install && react-native upgrade && react-native run-ios
```